What is the difference between various forms of Kali?
Maa Kali has various forms depicted as Adya Kali in Adyapeeth, Maa Tara in Tarapith, Maa Bhavatarini in Dakshineswar etc . Also she is worshipped as shaman Kali and ugra Tara in Hindu crematorium . Also she is sometimes referred as Bhadra Kali ,Guhya Kali ,Siddhi Kali . Can anyone explain the different forms of maa Kali as per th Hindu texts and what does the various forms of mother signify , what are their differences ? Thank you.

Sri Ramakrishna discusses various forms of Kali in Ramakrishna Kathamrita (The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna).

KESHAB (with a smile): "Describe to us, sir, in how many ways Kali,
the Divine Mother, sports in this world."
MASTER (with a smile): "Oh, She plays in different ways. It is She
alone who is known as Maha-Kali, Nitya-Kali, Smasana-Kali,
Raksha-Kali, and Syama-Kali. Maha-Kali and Nitya-Kali are mentioned in
the Tantra philosophy. When there were neither the creation, nor the
sun, the moon, the planets, and the earth, and when darkness was
enveloped in darkness, then the Mother, the Formless One, Maha-Kali,
the Great Power, was one with Maha-Kala, the Absolute.
"Syama-Kali has a somewhat tender aspect and is worshipped in the
Hindu households. She is the Dispenser of boons and the Dispeller of
fear. People worship Raksha-Kali, the Protectress, in times of
epidemic, famine, earthquake, drought, and flood. Smasana-Kali is the
embodiment of the power of destruction. She resides in the cremation
ground, surrounded by corpses, jackals, and terrible female spirits.
From Her mouth flows a stream of blood, from Her neck hangs a garland
of human heads, and around Her waist is a girdle made of human hands.
"After the destruction of the universe, at the end of a great cycle,
the Divine Mother garners the seeds for the next creation: She is like
the elderly mistress of the house, who has a hotchpotch-pot in which
she keeps different articles for household use. (All laugh.)
"Oh, yes! Housewives have pots like that, where they keep 'sea-foam',
(The Master perhaps referred to the cuttlefish bone found on the
seashore. The popular belief is that it is hardened sea-foam.) blue
pills, small bundles of seeds of cucumber, pumpkin, and gourd, and so
on. They take them out when they want them. In the same way, after the
destruction of the universe, my Divine Mother, the Embodiment of
Brahman, gathers together the seeds for the next creation. After the
creation the Primal Power dwells in the universe itself. She brings
forth this phenomenal world and then pervades it. In the Vedas
creation is likened to the spider and its web. The spider brings the
web out of itself and then remains in it. God is the container of the
universe and also what is contained in it.
"Is Kali, my Divine Mother, of a black complexion? She appears black
because She is viewed from a distance; but when intimately known She
is no longer so. The sky appears blue at a distance; but look at it
close by and you will find that it has no colour. The water of the
ocean looks blue at a distance, but when you go near and take it in
your hand, you find that it is colourless."

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, The Master with Keshab, translated by Swami Nikhilananda

My problem with Ramakrishna is that he didn't seem well versed in Hindu philosophy, nor really knowledgeable in early forms of Shakta tradition. A more early figure or scripture in the Shakta tradition will be more authoritative than him. Ramakrishna's bhakti was holistic and was not based on any Hindu tradition or scripture

What about adya Kali? What did he say about it. And the Kali idol present is Dakshineswar is called maa bhavatarini so which form of Kali is it Shyama or adya Kali.

He talks of adyasakti. As far as I know he does not say which form of Kali is Ma Bhabhatarini.
